# Python - overwrite constant from imported file and use in imported functions

Tags: python, python-import

I have a module where some constants are defined and also used in several functions. How can I over-ride their values from my main file ?

Say this is the module, `test_import.py`

```
MY_CONST = 1

def my_func(var = MY_CONST):
    print(var)
```

And this is my `main.py` file:

```
import test_import

MY_CONST = 2
test_import.MY_CONST = 3

test_import.my_func()
```

This code still prints "1". I want it to print some other value (obviously, without passing a value when calling `my_func()`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @JonSG : It certainly explains the "why", but not actually providing and answer on "how". But helpful, thank you! (even if counterintuitive title; for novices, at least :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value is stored with the function itself when the function is defined; it is not looked up in the global scope when the function is called without an argument.

```
>>> test_import.my_func.__defaults__[0]
1
```

You *can*, if you really want to, assign a new default value to be used.

```
>>> test_import.my_func.__defaults__[0] = 9
>>> test_import.my_func()
9
```